# SQL- Query with Powershell and Integrated Security as sheduled Task not working?

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have several scripts which run queries on databases triggered by powershell code and they are perfectly working. Lately a new server which only accepts integrated security has to be added to the script.

The user which is logged on to the Machine has no right to run queries on the newly added SQL Server.

The code below shows the query function which I normally use. The code works fine, when I run it in ise or right click -> "run with Powershell" But if I try to run the code with the task scheduler it does not work. Of course I added the privileged user to run the query in the details of the task ("When running the task, use the following user account"). I also tested various options like "Run with highest privileges"

I also tried to run another PS1 which creates credentials from an textfile in which the password for the user is stored encrypted and then run the Code with 
    "Start-Process powershell.exe -credential" but no luck.

```
function query_12 {
    param($SQL_Server_Name, $SQL_Table, $SQL_DB_NAME, $SQL_Query)
    #$SQL_Table = "[myTable]"
    #$SQL_Server_Name = "MYSERVER"
    #$SQL_DB_NAME = "myDB"
    #$SQL_Query = "SELECT * FROM $SQL_DB_NAME.$SQL_Table"

    $SQL_Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection('Connection Timeout=100')
    $SQL_Connection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQL_Server_Name; Database = $SQL_DB_NAME; Integrated Security = TRUE;"
    $SQL_Command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand; $SQL_Command.CommandText = $SQL_Query; $SQL_Command.Connection = $SQL_Connection; $SQL_Adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter; $SQL_Adapter.SelectCommand = $SQL_Command; $SQL_Dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

    $SQL_Adapter.Fill($SQL_Dataset)
    $SQL_Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]
    $SQL_Connection.Close()
}
```

Is there any known solution for this problem? I cannot find any, other than creating an dedicated user in SQL.

**Update**:

I've tested now several scenarios, here are the results:

Task created with Credentials of Privileged Account
--> batch runs PS1 = fail

Task created with Credentials of Privileged Account
--> directly run PS1 = fail

Task created with Credentials of Privileged Account
--> batch runs PS1 which Start-Process with "-Credential" = fail

Task created with local Account
--> RunAsRob runs batch which runs PS1 = success

It seems to work with runasrob but for me its only an *workaround*. There must be an OOTB Solution without additional Tools?!

Comment: I don't have a solution but I remember having this same problem a few years ago. Interestingly, the scheduled task did run successfully if the same account was logged in interactively at the time the task ran.

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Comment: @DanGuzman never tested that, but if it should its not really an solution

Comment: @Larnu Unfortunately i do not have access to the SQL Serverlog or Eventlog of the Server to see what happens in the Security or Application Area.
on the client- machine there happens the normal logon/logoff stuff without any errors when i run the task